# Get a file in a jar in jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a setup like this:

- outer.jar

  - inner.jar

    - file.txt

So, I am executing outer.jar and within it's main class:

```
URL url = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("file.txt");
```

url is: 'jar:file:outer.jar!/inner.jar!/file.txt'

But if I try to read it like:

```
url.openStream()
```

I get an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry inner.jar!/file.txt not found in outer.jar
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:142)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:150)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

The file is definitely there. Is this not possible with JarURLConnection?

Comment: try to avoid JAR-nesting - every nesting-level is rather expensive for your CPU AND doesnt make much sense. Simply slam all of the classes & resources into your one, big jar and reference them correctly - you wont even need the sourcecode for that to work ... just modify your buildsystem so that it append this bytecode immediately before the packaging-phase.

Comment: This is caused by using one-jar to package libraries in a single jar without exploding them as you suggest. Their website suggests my code should work though: http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using the Maven Shade Plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Answer (score 2):

Jar files are just simpler version of Zip files with other name, so it's just a matter of treating them as zip files:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;


public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = Main.class.getResource("file.jar");
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(url.getFile());
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            //InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry); <- to handle the file
            //print the names of the files inside the Jar
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE: This appears to be a **design problem** as it isn't recommended to have nested jar files.

*(Why don't you merge them?)*

Comment: "Jar" is fancier than "Zip"??

Comment: Yeah, but the name "Zip" has a lot more, uh, zip than does "Jar".

Comment: JARfiles are way more than simple ZIP-archives. They have manifests, fixed directory-structure, somewhat fixed compression as far as i remember, are executable and whatnot. The fact that one is able to read the JAR-archive via ZIP/UNZIP-algorithms ... basically comes down to the kindness of the original JAR-developers, thats about it. Everyone who treats JAR-files like ZIP either has no knowledge about the topic or just wants to sound smart OR has to solve rather exotic problems like this one right up there.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but unfortunately, I need to a way to use a URL for this, so your answer will not work.

Comment: Can't speak for the original asker but in my case, the reason I don't merge them is: (1) the classes in the jars would then be on the main classpath, which would clash with another version of the same library which is already there; (2) if I rename the packages, when using an IDE, renamed packages autocomplete when trying to complete the ones in the main library, making life less nice.